# I am getting a different maximum and minimum value here

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

It is a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered it prints out the largest and smallest of the numbers.

**Custom Inputs are given as follow:**

```sh
7
2
11
flip
10
4
done
```

Output:

Invalid Input

Maximum is 10

Minimum is 4

**Expected Output:**

**Invalid Input**

**Maximum is 11**

**Minimum is 2**

```
a=list()
while True:
    sval=input()
    if sval == "done":
        break    
    try:
        value=int(sval)
        a.append(value) 
    except:
        print("Invlid")
        continue



    def sml():
        val=a[0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i]<val:
                smalles=a[i]
        print("Minimum is",smalles)

    def lge():
        val=a[0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i]>val:
                larges=a[i]
        print("Maximum is",larges)

lge()
sml()
```

Comment: If any answer solves your problem then you should accept one of the appropriate answer as solution so that other contributors can ignore this question. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these loops:

```
        val=a[0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i]>val:
                larges=a[i]
```

you have two values, `val` and `largest`, when you really only want one (`largest`).  The idea of finding a maximum value is that you want to be comparing against the largest value you've found so far, and constantly updating it each time you find a larger value.

A much shorter way of writing this code would be:

```
a = []
while True:
    val = input()
    if val == "done":
        break
    try:
        a.append(int(val))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid")

print(max(a))
print(min(a))
```

Or, if you weren't allowed to use the `max` and `min` functions, you could simply maintain `largest` and `smallest` as you go, instead of keeping an array at all:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    val = input()
    if val == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid")
        continue
    if (largest, smallest) == (None, None):
        largest, smallest = num, num
    if largest < num:
        largest = num
    if smallest > num:
        smallest = num

print(largest)
print(smallest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the maximum and minimum value after appending to the array, you can find it before. This will reduce the cost of iterating the array each and every time to find the maximum and minimum.

```
a=list()
max_, min_ = float('-inf'), float('inf')
while True:
    sval=input()
    if sval == "done":
        break
    try:
        value = int(sval)
        if value > max_:
            max_ = value
        elif value < min_:
            min_ = value
        a.append(value)
    except:
        print("Invalid")
        continue

print("Maximum is", max_)
print("Minimum is", min_)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problems with your code

- Why your functions are in `while` loop
- Every time while finding small and large you are comparing with first value only

## Solution

Below is smallest possible changed answer from your code.

```py
a=list()
while True:
    sval=input()
    if sval == "done":
        break    
    try:
        value=int(sval)
        a.append(value) 
    except:
        print("Invlid")
        continue



def sml():
    smalles=a[0]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]<smalles:
            smalles=a[i]
    print("Minimum is",smalles)

def lge():
    larges=a[0]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]>larges:
            larges=a[i]
    print("Maximum is",larges)

lge()
sml()
```

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration you are comparing with first element of list i.e val (val = a[0])
and not updating the val .
Modify

## code

```py
a=list()
while True:
    sval=input()
    if sval == "done":
        break    
    try:
        value=int(sval)
        a.append(value) 
        print("Appended")
    except:
        print("Invlid")
        continue



    def sml():
        
        print(a)
        smalles=a[0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if smalles > a[i]:
                print(a[i] , end=" ")
                smalles=a[i]
        print()
        print("Minimum is",smalles)

    def lge():
        larges=a[0]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i]>larges:
                larges=a[i]
        print("Maximum is",larges)

lge()
sml()
```